# No seleccionar una palabra

Tags: r, regex

Tengo el siguiente df

```
datos2<-data.frame(
 col1=c("rojo1","morado1","verde4","amarillo","verde","rojo3"),
 col2=c(123,234,222,111,456,345)
)
```

```
      col1 col2
1    rojo1  123
2  morado1  234
3   verde4  222
4 amarillo  111
5    verde  456
6    rojo3  345
```

Si quisiera borrar el color rojo podría hacer

```
datos2$col3<-gsub("rojo\\d", "", datos2$col1)
```

```
      col1 col2     col3
1    rojo1  123         
2  morado1  234  morado1
3   verde4  222   verde4
4 amarillo  111 amarillo
5    verde  456    verde
6    rojo3  345
```

¿Cómo es para hacer lo contrario? Quedarme con el rojo y borrar todo lo demás, en plan

gsub( Lo contrario a "rojo\d", "", datos2$col1)

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta, me di cuenta que lo había entendido mal todo, espero ahora mi respuesta te pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo esta en al expresión regular, te dejo el enlace de la documentación para que puedas darle una chequeada:
[Documentación Exp. Regulares en R](https://rpubs.com/ydmarinb/429756#:%7E:text=Expresi%C3%B3n%20regular%2C%20tambi%C3%A9n%20conocida%20como,caracteres%20u%20operaciones%20de%20sustituciones.)

Sí lo que tu deseas realizar es obtener coincidencias de `rojo{digito}` entonces está bien tu exp. lo normal podría ser `"rojo\\d"` te va devolver las coincidencias de `rojo{digito}` pero si deseas lo contrario, quieres las no coincidencias de `rojo{digito}` bueno tenemos lo siguiente: `"^([^r]+[^o]+[^j]+[^o]+[^\\d]?)$"`

Donde primero le decimos que queremos que las palabras empiecen en `^` y finalicen `$` lo que esta entre el inicio y el final de toda la cadena queremos que no tenga las siguientes características: 
`^` (empieza en )
`[^r]+` (cualquier carácter que no sea r de uno a más)
`[^o]+` (seguido de cualquier carácter que no sea o de una a más)
`[^j]+` (seguido de cualquier carácter que no sea j de una a más)
`[^o]+` (seguido de cualquier carácter que no sea o de una a más)
`[^\\d]?` (seguido de cualquier **carácter** que no sea un digito y que puede aparecer una o muchas veces --prueba retirando este parámetro para que veas el comportamiento)
`$` (que finalice aquí)

Finalmente tú código sería algo similar ah (por favor lee los comentarios en el código):

```
datos2 <- data.frame(
 col1=c("rojo1","morado1","verde4","amarillo","verde","rojo3","abc123","123abc","1abc23"),
 col2=c(123,234,222,111,456,345,222,222,222)
)

datos2$col3 <- gsub("rojo\\d", "", datos2$col1) ## retira todas las COINCIDENCIAS de rojo{digito} del arreglo
datos2$col4 <- gsub("^([^r]+[^o]+[^j]+[^o]+[^\\d]?)$", "", datos2$col1) ## retira todas las NO COINCIDENCIAS de rojo{digito} del arreglo

print(datos2)
```

No olvides realizar la prueba que te comente.

Tu output sería
[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

Está muy bien el uso de expresiones regulares, pero aquí te dejo un método más sencillo que te puede servir.

Como la columna que estás creando depende de otra, entonces podemos hacerlo con un `ifelse()` y la función `grepl()`.

```
datos2$col4<-ifelse(grepl("rojo", datos2$col1), datos2$col1, "")

datos2
      col1 col2  col4
1    rojo1  123 rojo1
2  morado1  234      
3   verde4  222      
4 amarillo  111      
5    verde  456      
6    rojo3  345 rojo3
```

Con la función `grepl()` le indicamos a R que nos indique que filas de la columna `col1` contiene el caracter `rojo`, si es así, entonces que coloque el caracter completo, pero sino es así que coloque `""`. Esto de las condiciones lo hemos conseguido con la función `ifelse()`.